# RPM->installing a new version of a program which has different name

Tags: centos, rpmbuild

I need to install a version 2.2 of a program X. In repo the default version is 2.0. I built the rpm with `rpm-build` and I have an rpm called X-2.2. The program from the repo is called X2.0 so package manager does not recognise them as the same programs, I can not just update it.  What should I do to install the X-2.2 if it has conflicts with the previous repo version?

Comment: If it's not in the package manager's database, then it''s not going to see it as being an update. One thing that you can do is to install it separately in somewhere like `/opt` and prepend it too your  environment when you want to use it.

Comment: Are the conflicts with the previous version or with installed libraries? Can you add the messages to your question? Why can 't  you erase the 2.0 version before you try to install the new one?

Comment: I guess some apps depends on the previous version. And if I install in /opt instead of /usr/local how the app for that requires this rpm will find it in /opt?

Comment: Did you manually create a `spec` file for this package, or did the source you used to generate the RPM provide all necessary dependencies?
The `spec` file should declare the package `Name`, `Requires`, `Conflicts`, and `Provides` such that the package manager can then resolve those when you try to install.

Comment: I created manually the SPCE file. The installation ends up with conflicts of some doc file in /usr/share.

Comment: If you can find the spec file that was used to generate the RPM in the repo, you could try to copy it (or just use it directly, unless it's making a bunch of specific patches against the 2.0 version). For instance, for Fedora packages, you can find the spec files for the packages here: https://src.fedoraproject.org/

Comment: That is interesting info. But I am still looking for the "right way" to solve this kind of problems...

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your question and provide more information about your requirements, i.e., do you want to have two versions simultaneously installed? Or do you want to replace version 2.0 with 2.2 (understanding that it may require additional changes if other system packages depend on version 2.0)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [Obsoletes:](https://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html) tag to your RPM spec:

```
Name: X
Version: 2.2
Obsoletes: X2.0 <= %{version}
```

Or you can make it Provide the dependency:

```
Name: X
Version: 2.2
Provides: X2.0 = 2.2
```

They both behave differently on how upgrades and dependency resolution occurs.  The Obsolutes tag should provide for better upgrades but can cause problems if you try to install the older package.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.